# Key reasons for golang to make concurrency easier

Tags: go

Is my understanding roughly right below?

- `go` can *mostly* detect `dead lock` at compile-time.
- That `go` can use `chan` to minimize `race condition` is because only single sender or receiver `goroutine` can have access to any specific `chan` at a time.

Comment: Go *cannot* detect any deadlock at compile time, and only a specific case as runtime. The second point is probably incorrect too, but the wording is imprecise. Many goroutines can access send and receive operations on a single goroutine.

Comment: oops, that last "goroutine" was supposed to be "channel"

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that's accurate. On the first point there aren't any compile time guarantees about dead locking, if you use a mutex poorly you will be dead locking, no compiler can prevent that. You can test for race conditions easily, but that's different.

On the second point, the channel serializes your asynchronous operations but I don't think how you state it makes much sense. A bunch of goroutines can be writing to and reading from it. It's just like a queue to put the data in, no coordination is guaranteed. You won't panic due to multiple routines reading off it or writing to it at the same time but if you have that happening Go isn't doing anything to make your program work well, you have to coordinate the routines yourself using channels.

Comment: Yes, a `chan` is just like a `queue` but its concurrent access is scheduled  by not `app` but `go` .

Answer (score 2):

No, the first is completely wrong and the second is at least stated unclear or strange.

Answer (score -2):

According to this tutorial, it can catch some deadlocks. I've not gone though this tutorial though...

http://guzalexander.com/2013/12/06/golang-channels-tutorial.html[enter link description here](http://guzalexander.com/2013/12/06/golang-channels-tutorial.html)

Comment: At _runtime_, not compile time as stated by the OP.